# What does "in den Fokus rücken" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I am trying to find out what the collocation **"in den Fokus rücken"** means.
*- move the focus? 
- to be at the center of attention? 
- become the focus?*

I am really not sure. I am especially wondering, if it means that something is at the center of attention, with no reference meaning to the past, or if it means that something got back to be at the center of attention, like it was in the past, then no more, then now once again.

The sentence I am trying to translate it from is this:

*"..Sie haben (gewisse Ergebnisse) aber eine heftige Debatte erzeugt, die den Unterricht wieder stärker in den Fokus rückt".*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite literal:

***im Fokus*** is the center of attention and
***rücken*** means to move something.

So you if you have ***in den* Fokus rücken** you to move it to the center of attention, or put a spotlight on it. At the moment just before, there was no special attention or focus on the object you are talking about.

The preceding ***wieder*** (=again) on the other hand indicates that the object *was* in the focus at some earlier time.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to translate the sentence you have quoted, based on the context. Especially "Unterricht" can be translated in different ways, e.g. classes or eduction. One possibility could be

"They (some events) have started a heated debate, which moved the classes back into the focus (of the discussion)." or (more freely) "..., which brought the problems with education back into the focus." I hope you get the idea...

In any case, the "...Unterricht **wieder** stärker..." indicates that the focus was there in the past, then was lost, and is now coming back. Without this "wieder", there would be no reference to the past, indicating that this is the first time that the focus would be on the eduction issues.